# Concat two DF's excluding rows not in one df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have two pandas dfs:

```
df1
 id_event    id_indiv        odds
0    11545      3131       0.185185
1    11545      4529       0.088106
2    11545      9168       0.055402
3    11545     12922       0.088106
4    11545     12929       0.270270
5    11545     19936       0.037523
6    11545     24703       0.202020
7    11545     25951       0.043573
8    11545     26397       0.029762
9    11545     28177       0.219780

df2
    id_event  id_indiv  final_odds
0     11545      3131    0.215054
1     11545      4526   -1.000000
2     11545      4529    0.060423
3     11545      9168    0.050251
4     11545     12922    0.060423
5     11545     12929    0.250000
6     11545     19936    0.019900
7     11545     24703    0.392157
8     11545     25951    0.052910
9     11545     26397    0.034014
10    11545     28177    0.377358
```

In this example, there is one individual who has final odds of -1.00, which makes it easy to drop values that are less than 0:

```
df2.drop(df2[df2['final_odds']<0].index, inplace = True)
```

However, after running this command, the resulting DF's are not the same size:

```
df1
[8781 rows x 38 columns]

df2
[8737 rows x 38 columns]
```

The DFs contain thousands of events and individuals.
I need to concat the two dfs such that the resulting df has the following shape:

```
df3
 id_event     id_indiv       odds       final_odds        
0    11545      3131       0.185185     0.215054
1    11545      4529       0.088106     0.060423
2    11545      9168       0.055402     0.050251
3    11545     12922       0.088106     0.060423
4    11545     12929       0.270270     0.250000
5    11545     19936       0.037523     0.019900
6    11545     24703       0.202020     0.392157
7    11545     25951       0.043573     0.052910
8    11545     26397       0.029762     0.034014
9    11545     28177       0.219780     0.377358
```

I tried executing creating a new temporary df which only contains rows that exist in df1 using this command but receive an error:

```
temp_df = df1.drop(df2[df2['id_indiv'] !=df1['id_indiv'] | df2['id_event']  != df1['id_event']].index )

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Is there a way to concat these two dfs to get a resulting df matching my above expected output?
I believe the final df should be 8737 x 38 columns in size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us make it more easy just do `merge`

```
df2.drop(df2[df2['final_odds'] < 0].index, inplace = True)
m = df1[['id_event','id_indiv']].agg(tuple,1).isin(df1[['id_event','id_indiv']].agg(tuple,1))
df1 = df1[m]
```

Also with `merge`

```
df2.drop(df2[df2['final_odds'] < 0].index, inplace = True)
df1 = df1.merge(df2.drop_duplicates(['id_event','id_indiv']),how='right')
```

Comment: I should've clarified in my original post but the original dfs are of different size: df1 8781 rows, df2  9701 rows, after executing the above code, I get the following error: KeyError: '[8804 8833 8855 8858 8866 8903 8934 8949 8961 8964 8972 8974 9010 9014\n 9024 9034 9036 9040 9041 9050 9051 9052 9058 9063 9080 9084 9092 9097\n 9098 9109 9119 9127 9154 9165 9185 9189 9207 9208 9210 9217 9222 9238\n 9249 9250 9261 9267 9277 9348 9367 9375 9379 9405 9412 9474 9479 9539\n 9561 9584 9590 9633 9639 9686] not found in axis'

Comment: Do you mind explaining the .agg(tuple, 1) argument? is it creating a tuple of the id_event, and id_indiv and then checking if that tuple is in the tuple from the other df, but I dont understand what the 1 is for

Comment: @Redratz that is mean by every row , we create a tuple axis=1

Answer (score 1):

**A) If you believe there are duplicates in the id columns**

First, let's get the subset of the df2 you are interested in.

```
df2_subset = df2[df2['final_odds']>=0]

# Then, eliminate duplicates based on the subset ['id_event','id_indiv']
df2_subset = df2_subset.groupby(['id_event','id_indiv'], as_index=False).nth(0)
```

Once we have the df2_subset, we can merge.

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on=['id_event','id_indiv'],how='left')
```

**B) If you know that there are no duplicates in the id columns**

You can solve your problem in just one line.

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2[df2['final_odds']>=0], on=['id_event','id_indiv'],how='left')
```